# submit form when p:commandbutton click

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces in my JSF web application. In order to get user inputs I have used primefaces keyboard component and it's working fine. Issue is after getting user input from keyboard component and click on commandButton cause for page reload.

```
<p:keyboard id="default" value="#{paymentBean.mobileNumber}" keypadOnly="true" size="50" for="numberInput" />

<p:commandButton id="enterNoteBtn" action="#{paymentBean.validatePayment()}" value="#{msg['billpayment.cash.message']}" 
                            onclick="onEnterNoteBtn();" async="true" />
```

But when using primefaces inputText instead of keyboard component it will not cause for a page reload.

```
<p:inputText id="numberInput" value="#{paymentBean.mobileNumber}"  autocomplete="off" />

<p:commandButton id="enterNoteBtn" action="#{paymentBean.validatePayment()}" value="#{msg['billpayment.cash.message']}" 
                            onclick="onEnterNoteBtn();" async="true" />
```

I want to figure out the reason for this behavior (I am using primefaces version 5.3.1).

UPDATE :

I have found that cause for the page submit is the javascript function invoke on button click.

```
function onEnterNoteBtn(){
    var number = document.getElementById("cashForm:numberInput").value;
}
```

This is causing for form to submit because of invalid ID.

Thanks.

Comment: change your `action` to `actionListener` and also change the signature of `validatePayment` to `validatePayment(ActionEvent event)`. No need to pass any argument in `ELExpression` of `actionLisntener`. You can remove the `async="true"` because the default for `p:commandButton` is `ajax="true"`

Comment: Maybe the refresh process is too quick and you can not see the reload. So check the send and receive in your page after clicking on the button using firebug or chrome development tools. `action` must result in reload.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I'll try.

Comment: Read [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and improve your question